# Compare Cumulative Sales per Year-End

Tags: pandas, seaborn

Using this sample dataframe:

```
np.random.seed(1111)
df = pd.DataFrame({
'Category':np.random.choice( ['Group A','Group B','Group C','Group D'], 10000),
'Sub-Category':np.random.choice( ['X','Y','Z'], 10000),
'Sub-Category-2':np.random.choice( ['G','F','I'], 10000),
'Product':np.random.choice( ['Product 1','Product 2','Product 3'], 10000),
'Units_Sold':np.random.randint(1,100, size=(10000)),
'Dollars_Sold':np.random.randint(100,1000, size=10000),
'Customer':np.random.choice(pd.util.testing.rands_array(10,25,dtype='str'),10000),
'Date':np.random.choice( pd.date_range('1/1/2016','12/31/2020',  
                      freq='M'), 10000)})
```

I am trying to compare 12 month time frames with seaborn plots for a sub-grouping of category. For example, I'd like to compare the cumulative 12 months for each year ending 4-30 vs. the same time period for each year. I cannot wrap my head around how to get a running total of data for each respective year (5/1/17-4/30/18, 5/1/18-4/30/19, 5/1/19-4/30/20). The dates are just examples - I'd like to be able to compare different year-end data points, even better would be able to compare 365 days. For instance, I'd love to compare 3/15/19-3/14/20 to 3/15/18-3/14/19, etc.

I envision a graph for each 'Category' (A,B,C,D) with lines for each respective year representing the running total starting with zero on May 1, building through April 30 of the next year. The x axis would be the month (starting with May 1) & y axis would be 'Units_Sold' as it grows.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

One way to convert the date to fiscal quarters and extract the fiscal year:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':pd.date_range('2019-01-01', '2019-12-31', freq='M'),
                   'Values':np.arange(12)})
df['fiscal_year'] = df.Date.dt.to_period('Q-APR').dt.qyear
```

Output:

```
         Date  Values  fiscal_year
0  2019-01-31       0         2019
1  2019-02-28       1         2019
2  2019-03-31       2         2019
3  2019-04-30       3         2019
4  2019-05-31       4         2020
5  2019-06-30       5         2020
6  2019-07-31       6         2020
7  2019-08-31       7         2020
8  2019-09-30       8         2020
9  2019-10-31       9         2020
10 2019-11-30      10         2020
11 2019-12-31      11         2020
```

And now you can group by `fiscal_year` to your heart's content.

Comment: Thanks, Quang! One question - why did you use to_period('Q-APR') instead of 'A-APR'? I also am not sure how to take this information to then graph. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Honestly, I did not know that `'A-APR'` is a thing :D. It certainly is a better solution so you don't need to do `dt.qyear` :-)